# Write a C++ program using nested loops to output the following numbers to the screen?

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I wrote a C++ program, but the output I got was unexpected (as shown below).

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
main()
{
int a,b;
for(a=3;a<=21;a+=2)
    {
    printf("\n");
    for(b=1;b<a;b+=2)
        {
        cout<<setw(2)<<a+b-1<<" ";
        }
    }
cout<<"\n";
}
```

Can someone help me tweak it, so it runs like this:

[image]

Comment: Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, rather require people to read links from out site resources (or pictures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
main()
{
int a,b;
for(a = 1 ;a <= 10; a++)
{
    for(b = 2 * a + 1;b <= 3 * a; b++)
    {
        cout<<setw(2)<<b<<" ";
    }
    printf("\n");
}
cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, the output of this method is similar to what has been given by Paul (y)

Comment: Yes, both solutions are correct, but for me, my code is clearer. Paul's solution is nice as well, though.

Comment: @OdieArdhia, you can accept an answer (either mine or Paul's) by clicking on the checkbox, so in the future, people having similar problems will be directed to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
    int i = 3;
    int numcols = 1;

    while(i <= 21)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < numcols; j++)
        {
            cout << i + j << '\t';
        }
        cout << '\n';
        i += 2;
        numcols += 1;
    }
}
```

If `tab` is too wide, you can replace it with a double space.

Answer (score 1):

Catch!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const size_t N = 24;

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number less than " << N << " (0 - exit): ";

        size_t n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        if ( !n ) break;

        if ( N < n  ) n = N;

        std::cout << std::endl;

        for ( size_t i = 0, x = 3; i < n; i++, x += 2 )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) std::cout << std::setw( 4 ) << x + j;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 10 then the output will be

```
Enter a non-negative number less than 24 (0 - exit): 10
   3
   5   6
   7   8   9
   9  10  11  12
  11  12  13  14  15
  13  14  15  16  17  18
  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30

Enter a non-negative number less than 24 (0 - exit): 0
```

The loops can be written also the following way

```
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 4 ) << 2 * i + 3 + j;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: The way that you give actually cool,
I just don't need to input the numbers when running the program

Answer (score 0):

```
int a,b = 0;
for(a=3;a<=21;a+=2)
{
    printf("\n");
    b++;
    for(int i =0;i < b;i++)
    {
        cout<<setw(2)<<a+i<<" ";
    }
```

increment `b` outside of the inner loop so you can keep a count of how many numbers you want on each line.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the second loop you have it Starting at 1, if you would set this as b=a it will help you allot since you will only need to have std::cout<

This above will probably be the only change you need to make.